# Impossible to connect to PostgreSQL DB via VBA

Tags: excel, postgresql, ms-access, vba

I have a problem trying to connect to my local `PGSQL` db via `VBA`. My code looks like this :

`Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 strCnx = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode}; Server=127.0.0.1; Database=postgres; 
 UID=postgres;Pwd=***;port=5432"
 conn.Open strCnx`

The error I get is

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Controler]DATA SOURCE NAME NOT FOUND AND NO
>   DEFAULT DRIVER SPECIFIED

I have tried a few things I found on `stackoverflow`, mainly installed the `odbc` drivers for `postgresqlx64`, and tried to connect to the database using directly `ODBC`, which told me *success* when I tried to connect (picture below).

[Testing connection to PGSQL DB directly via ODBC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdHyM.png)

But despite everything I tried, the error is the same when I try to execute my VBA code, and I'm out of ideas, so if there are any way you could help me, I would be most thankful :)

Thanks

Frost

Comment: Are you using 32-bits Access or 64-bits Access?

Comment: I installed the 64 bits drivers and tried to use the PostgreSQL Unicode driver. In the picture, the PostgreSQL35W datasource is the 64bits unicode driver (I assumed x64 stands for x86_64 bits and x86 for 32 bits, but maybe I made a mistake though )

Comment: I'm asking if your Access application is 32-bits or 64-bits, not your ODBC driver... Those need to be matched. I deduced you used the 64-bits driver from your post.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I use excel, 32 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install an ODBC driver with the same bitness as the application hosting your VBA. So 32-bits Excel means you need the 32-bits (x86) ODBC driver.

If you install the proper ODBC driver, this error should go away.

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much. I feel kinda dumb, I had assumed all MS office apps were in 64 bits, and that the driver was accounting for the x86/amd_64 version of PGSQL. 

Thanks again ! :)